# Converter timestamp p/data no LUA?

Tags: lua, timestamp

Como converter timestamp para data legível no LUA ?

tipo
1634521166 (2021-10-18T01:39:25)

Answer (score 3):

Use [os.date()](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.date)

```lua
os.date('%Y-%m-%dT%X', 1634521166) -- retorna '2021-10-18T01:39:26'
```

ou ou troque o primeiro parâmetro para '*t' para retornar uma table

```lua
os.date('*t', 1634521166).year -- retorna '2021'
```

Comment: Mais informações sobre data no lua neste [link](https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html)